# In google sheets, how to replace #N/A in column A with corresponding value in column B

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Please find the below image for your reference]

Please find the below image for the clear understanding on what exactly i need. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: try to use =filter(ifna(a1:a,b1:b),a1:a<>"")

Answer (score 0):

You should write formula for column C

```
=IF(A2 = "N/A", B2, A2)
```

Please check this sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DvXAZQKjso2FlbpT_hGX_SArAMd1O5Kcd2EomZyPp1I/edit?usp=sharing

After opening this sheet follow the following steps:

1. `Highlight` all cells you need to modify.
2. Take all formulas to the clipboard by pressing `Ctrl+C` on your keyboard.
3. Then press `Ctrl+Shift+V` to paste back the values only:

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by

```
=IFERROR(A1,B1)
```

N/A is not a string so I don't think IF will work here.

and this will not only replace #N/A but also any kind of errors

Comment: Happy to Help :)